# Probability a students is present

Tags: probability

A student is presented in the exam knowing 85 questions of 100 possible questions. In the exam, randomly, three questions are withdrawn. Find the probability of the event A: "the student will know the three questions withdrawn".

Answer (score 1):

If God help him the first question will be among the 85 he does know, the second in 84 and last in 83 the probability will be:
$\mathbb{P}(A)=\frac{85}{100}\times\frac{84}{99}\times\frac{83}{98}$